# Is 我携带我的猫 grammaticaly correct?

Tags: translation, grammar, mandarin

I've been writing Chinese sentences just to get myself used to the language, and I tried writing the sentence *I carry my cat*. I translated this to `我携带我的猫` (Pinyin: wǒ xié dài wǒ de māo). It sounds odd to have another instance of `wǒ` in the same sentence.
Is this sentence correct?

Comment: yes it is correct.  Just that it sounds tenseless. And usually just 带 is enough,  携带 sounds too formal.

Comment: The common meaning of 携带 implies 随身带着, i.e. the thing you carry is supposed to be stably kept close to your body, so we don't say 携带 an animal.

Comment: It sounds better if you say 我带我的猫. It's feels too formal to say 携带.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a sign, it is common to see "不可攜帶寵物", "請勿攜犬入內".

However, we seldom use "攜" or "攜帶" in ordinary text; simply "帶" is okay.

Answer (score 2):

Usually we don't use animals as the object of 携带, but using animals after 带 is ok.

For example: 我带我的猫一起去旅行。 I carry my cat while travelling.

Answer (score 1):

我携带我的猫。This sentence is grammatically correct.We Chinese people are more used to.我抱(着)我的猫 or我带(着)我的猫。

Answer (score 0):

我携带我的猫 is grammatically correct.

I'd say that 携带 and 带 have a difference in register. We usually find 携带 in signs or instructions (eg. websites of airlines), which are much formal. But generally speaking, in texts or even conversations, we use 带

Answer (score 0):

I would say 带着 is better than 携带
I believe most of users use the second one